# downloading html through mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

Here I am in a problem while converting HTML to PDF using mPDF. I have done the following code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['imp1']))
    {
    require_once 'mpdf60/mpdf.php';
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0); 

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;  // 
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/style.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$test= "<html><body><table><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table></body></html>";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($test, 2);

$mpdf->Output();  
exit();    

    }
    ?>
```

This code is working fine but while am adding the following stylesheet in the header...the code is not working...

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

    <link href="/test7/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/test7/assets/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/test7/assets/css/bootstrap-flat.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/test7/assets/css/invoiceform.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I am simply wrecking my head why this is creating the issue

Comment: What do you mean, "not working"?  Tell us what behavior you want and what you actually get.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom...while clicking on the button the page is getting loaded but no PDF is displaying

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom..."not working" means while clicking on the button am getting "Failed to load PDF document" in screen

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have figured it out...the issue is in HEADER...I have put the  code block in before the stylesheet declaration.

```
<head>
    <?
    if(isset($_POST['imp1']))
        {
        require_once 'mpdf60/mpdf.php';
    $mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0); 

    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

    $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;  // 
    $stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/style.css');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
    $test= "<html><body><table><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table></body></html>";
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($test, 2);

    $mpdf->Output();  
    exit();    

        }
        ?>

<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

    <link href="/test7/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/test7/assets/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/test7/assets/css/bootstrap-flat.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/test7/assets/css/invoiceform.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
```